# pipewire dependencies break 20.04 to 22.4 upgrade

Tags: system-installation, dependencies

Starting from 20.04 I ran the upgrade.  Ended up with my computer booting to a cli.  No data loss or anything, I just can't run desktop.   If I try to run desktop I get

gstreamer1.0-pipewire :
Depends: pipewire (= 0.3.48-1ubuntu1) but 0.3.52-1 is to be installed
Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0 (= 0.3.48-1ubuntu1) but 0.3.52-1 is to be installed

(the numbers are close: I'm repeating them from memory - it is 0.3.52 installed whereas some package expects 0.3.48)

Thinking of options, my understanding is that backing pipewire down to 0.3.48 would really mess up a lot of other dependencies, so a pipewire backdown is really not a good solution.
Another option is to reinstall either 20.04 or 22.4 over the top of my current install
Perhaps the easiest solutio, if its possible, is to find the program that wants 0.3.48 and (hopefully) chnage that in a .conf file.
How can I get past my computer wanting to have 0.3.48 when 0.3.52 is bering installed?  Or, do I just reinstall my O/S?

Comment: The only package *in the Ubuntu repositories* that depends upon the `gstreamer1.0-pipewire` package is `gnome-shell`. So that suggests two possibilities: 1) You installed something else that depends upon that exact version of `gstreamer1.0-pipewire`. Ask apt what it is and then uninstall it. 2) Your release-upgrade had multiple errors that you did not include in your Question. Review your logs and include complete information.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy pipewire libpipewire-0.3-0` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422569/edit) to your question.

Comment: Here is how I solved this issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424596/after-upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-from-to-22-04-there-is-only-command-line-interface-g/1425059#1425059

Comment: An update.  First, thanks for the anwers.  Unfortunately, what has happened is that now the system won't even boot to the CLI.  I get to GRUB, select Ubuntu, and I see all the verbose messages zip by ending in a hang.   So I think I'm just going to reinstall my OSs (both Windows and Ubuntu).  Then I'll put the old nvme drive in with the new system and will copy all data to my new nvme disk.  Should get me a clean install of everything anyway.  Sigh....

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when trying to install ubuntu-desktop after upgrade. Adding this ppa solved it:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream

Comment: this fixed the problem for me it was just ppa issue