# After upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 from to 22.04 there is only command line interface, GUI doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, dependencies, 22.04, gui

[image]Ubuntu cannot login Graphical User Interface. when try to install

> sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

Says some packages could not be installed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies
gstreamer1.0-pipewire : depends: pipewire(=0.3.48-1ubuntu1) but it is not installable.
E: Unable unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I uninstalled pipewire and that dependencies.

> Startx

Also not working

For more information check this image.

Comment: It's hard to help without a full error message. You can at least post a picture of the output if you can't copy and paste.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` and post the output.

Comment: Also not working, this time 3 pipewire dependencies unmet error

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how I solved this problem

I manually edited the status file using nano

> sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status

and removed pipewire Ubuntu 20.04 dependencies paragraphs and saved

**Note, I'm not remove packages**

then

> sudo apt update

> sudo apt upgrade

now I can log in Graphical User Interface

refrence

[I can't remove packages that have unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279472/i-cant-remove-packages-that-have-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this ppa solved the issue for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Actually, I solved this issue and then answered my question. Your method doesn't work for me. Anyway, thanks for your participant.